# When I am trying to use 'git push heroku master' it returns me 'error: src refspec master does not match any'

Tags: django, git, heroku

I am reading the book: **Django for beginners: build websites with Python and Django** and do everything just like in the book. I will describe everything that i did.

Everything is working in local server and i want to deploy it into production with Heroku. I signed up and went to git cmd and entered to my folder. Order  of actions:

1. `$ pipenv shell`
2. `$ pipenv lock`
3. `$ touch Procfile`
4. write `web: gunicorn pages_project.wsgi --log-file -` in Procfile
5. `$ pipenv install gunicorn==19.9.0`
6. in settings.py update `ALLOWED_HOSTS=[]`to `ALLOWED_HOSTS['*']`
7. `$ heroku create`
8. `$  heroku git:remote -a *NAME*` 
     #example:  heroku git:remote -a morning-brook-95121
9. `$ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1`

To this place all was pretty good. Without errors. But next command is:

`$ git push heroku master`

I get this error:

> error: src refspec master does not match any
>   error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/morning-brook-95121.git'

Could anyone help me solve this problem please?

Comment: Please don't use, and especially don't link to, pirated material.

Comment: The error message `src refspec master does not match any` means you don't have a `master` branch locally. *Why* you don't have one is not obvious to me from your steps (there's no `git init` or `git clone` shown and I have never used heroku).

Comment: torek, i did all my steps again with git init and i got the same result.  If you know how to deploy django project by another  way, please, share it with me, i will infinitely thankful to you